# Coordinator layout with viewpager, scroll doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-scroll

I am working on this environment,

```
compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
```

with these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
```

I want to make a view with a coordinatorlayout but containing a viewPager, not a recyclerview. this is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My problem is that the scroll doesn't work for the view. I see some posts that implementing the onTouch method to simulate the scroll, but i want to work with the coordinatorLayout.
Thanks.

Comment: What layouts do you need coordinated here? In other words, what is wrong with LinearLayout, for example?

Comment: Are you trying to do this? https://gist.github.com/iPaulPro/1468510f046cb10c51ea#gistcomment-1471485 You are missing a CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: yes i'm trying to do this but the pager that i have doesn't contain a recyclerview, it contain LinearLayout that contain components.

Comment: Okay, so you have a LinearLayout that isn't scrolling? And why is it that a problem? LinearLayout doesn't scroll. Regardless of a ViewPager. You need a Scrollview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```xml
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
    
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>

<!--Wrap content will not work here you have to give fix height-->

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: You should add **android:fillViewport="true"** to NestedScrollView tag.

Answer (score 8):

To work with CoordinatorLayout it needs a View that implements NestedScrollingChild interface inside the ViewPager, like NestedScrollView. So, nest your LinearLayout as child of a NestedScrollView.